# OpenLDAP : Confidentiality required for ldapmodify (ldapi://)

Tags: ssl, openldap

I'm asking your help beacause i'm stuck since 2 days about that.

After i have setting up TLS and SSL on my OpenLDAP server, it works fine but i can not execute command anymore to edit the configuration.
When i try to change the configuration with a command like this : `ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///`
It return me an error like :

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Confidentiality required (13)
additional info: TLS confidentiality required
```

And when i specify ssl connection by adding `-Z` or `-ZZ` on the command this return me this error :

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Authentication method not supported (7)
additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available:
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to resolve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default SSF value for LDAPI access is 71 which is below the default value of required *minssf* in attribute *olcSaslSecProps*.

So instead of lowering the required SSF value you should set attribute *olcLocalSSF* to a higher value.

To have the ldapi connection working, the *olcLocalSSF* have to be equal or higher than *olcSecurity*

Example :

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLocalSSF
olcLocalSSF: 128
-
replace: olcSecurity
olcSecurity: ssf=128
```

In this example, `128` is the minimum number of bits required for the cryptographic key. All connections with key below that value will be denied

Normally values of the key lenght would be 40, 56, 64, 128, 164 and 256